# Adicionar caminho ao fileField ao clicar na imagem com YII framework

Tags: php, html, jquery, yii

Estou tentando fazer um esquema com fileField do YII framework para quando um usuário clicar na imagem que está na tela, o nome da imagem clicada aparecerá no span e o valor do model no fileField receberá a imagem. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer o fileField receber esse imagem ao clicar.

Aqui está o trecho do código do fileField:

```
 <span class="form-control"></span>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'des_imagem', array('id' => 'imagemxd', 'style' => 'width: 60%', 'value' => 'text', 'onchange'=>'$(this).parent().parent().find(".form-control").html($(this).val().split(/[\\\|/]/).pop());', 'style'=>'display: none;','name'=>'produto_image','accept'=>'image/*')); ?>
```

Aqui está o trecho do código da imagem:

```
echo CHtml::image($string, '', array( 'onclick' => "$(this).parent().find('input[type=image]').click();", 'id' => 'cimagem', 'style' => 'width: 50%;' ));
```

OBS: não sei se algo muda para essa questão, mas tudo está na mesma div.

Comment: Aparentemente você está tentando exibir a imagem sem antes efetuar o upload dela. Não conseguirá exibir dessa forma, com a imagem ainda no cliente.

Comment: Como assim upload? Pois o envio da imagem só ocorrera depois que eu clicar em um botão de salvar. A minha ideia era ela aparecer no span assim que clicar. Me desculpe se estou falando besteira mas sou novo em yii.

Answer (score 2):

Se você puder implementar javascript, pode fazer um preview utilizando o [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL), veja um exemplo:

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Prévia da imagem...">
```

Comment: Então, eu tenho algo assim na pagina já em outra funcionalidade. Porém a minha dúvida está justamente na parte de adicionar a imagem, pois eu quero adicionar a imagem que já está apresentada na tela, e assim quando eu clicar nela, irá ser adicionada como esse exemplo que me mostrou

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você está querendo. O preview da imagem não afeta o uso dela para upload.

Comment: Sim, não afeta. Mas a questão é que a imagem que eu estou dizendo já está na tela, ela veio carregada de um banco de imagens e é fixa. Porém quando ele clica nessa imagem, eu precisava que o campo file field (que é responsável por guardar o path de uma imagem selecionada qualquer), guardasse o caminho da imagem clicada.